# zig error when compiling `comptime` tuples & array pointers

Tags: arrays, zig

## the issue

Code:

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
const std = @import("std");

export fn main() void {
    works();
    //failsAtComptime();
}

fn works() void {
    const test_cases = .{
        [_]u8{},
        [_]u8{0x01},
    };

    inline for (test_cases) |case| {
        std.debug.print("{any}", .{&case});
    }
}

// Differences described in comments
fn failsAtComptime() void {
    // We instead make the test cases into a tupe *of tuples*...
    const test_cases = .{
        .{0, [_]u8{}},
        .{1, [_]u8{0x01}},
    };

    inline for (test_cases) |case| {
        // ...which is unpacked into the same values as in `works()`
        std.debug.print("{any}", .{&case[1]});
    }
}
```

Link to code [on CompilerExplorer](https://zig.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:zig,selection:(endColumn:37,endLineNumber:30,positionColumn:37,positionLineNumber:30,selectionStartColumn:37,selectionStartLineNumber:30,startColumn:37,startLineNumber:30),source:%27//+Type+your+code+here,+or+load+an+example.%0Aconst+std+%3D+@import(%22std%22)%3B%0A%0Aexport+fn+main()+void+%7B%0A++++works()%3B%0A++++//failsAtComptime()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn+works()+void+%7B%0A++++const+test_cases+%3D+.%7B%0A++++++++%5B_%5Du8%7B%7D,%0A++++++++%5B_%5Du8%7B0x01%7D,%0A++++%7D%3B%0A%0A++++inline+for+(test_cases)+%7Ccase%7C+%7B%0A++++++++std.debug.print(%22%7Bany%7D%22,+.%7B%26case%7D)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A//+Differences+described+in+comments%0Afn+failsAtComptime()+void+%7B%0A++++//+We+instead+make+the+test+cases+into+a+tupe+*of+tuples*...%0A++++const+test_cases+%3D+.%7B%0A++++++++.%7B0,+%5B_%5Du8%7B%7D%7D,%0A++++++++.%7B1,+%5B_%5Du8%7B0x01%7D%7D,%0A++++%7D%3B%0A%0A++++inline+for+(test_cases)+%7Ccase%7C+%7B%0A++++++++//+...which+is+unpacked+into+the+same+values+as+in+%60works()%60%0A++++++++std.debug.print(%22%7Bany%7D%22,+.%7B%26case%5B1%5D%7D)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Zig+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.456534281440305,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:z0100,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:zig,libs:!(),options:%27%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+zig+0.10.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:28.034676166012943,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27zig+0.10.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+zig+0.10.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:21.508789552546745,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

Specifically, the function `works()` ...works. And the function `failsAtComptime()` fails to compile, with an error code (139 for zig version 0.10.0, and 133 for zig trunk as of posting) but no error message.

Notably, this works if I change the print values to the raw arrays `case`/`case[1]`, instead of the array pointers `&case`/`&case[1]`.

## question

what's going wrong with `failsAtComptime`? Is this a user error (me?), or a compiler issue, or an error with CompilerExplorer?

Comment: I think you should open a bug report for Zig. I don't think it's a user error if the compiler crashes with no reasonable error message. (FYI I get `Trace/breakpoint trap`, which I think is what return code 133 means, using Zig `0.11.0-dev.2620+23ac4dd87`)

Comment: @mkrieger1 yeahhhh fair point. I always ask SO first by habit, so I don't bug the lang maintainers with user issues. But you're right, this is quite bizarre. And if you repro'd it on your machine then it's not just CompilerExplorer. thanks!

Comment: Zig issue: https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/15851